# Populating page with JSON from id in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a product page where user can add items to a basket. Once the item is added its stores the product ID in the local storage. I would like to be able to then add all the items they selected to the cart page, displaying the price, name and image. I'm not really sure how to go about this, please could you help me out.

data structure with each product having a unique ID:

```
{
  "products": [{
        "id": "0",
        "name": "Logitech G910 Orion Spectrum RGB Mechanical Gaming Keyboard - UK-Layout",
        "price": "119.99",
        "category": "0",
        "description": "Logitech 920-008017 G910 Orion Spectrum RGB Mechanical Gaming Keyboard - Black.",
        "images": [{
            "id": "0",
            "src": "images/00.jpg"
          },
          {
            "id": "1",
            "src": "images/01.jpg"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "src": "images/02.jpg"
          }
        ]
      },
```

Code that adds an item to a basket:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', '.cartbutton', function() {
    var row = $(this).parents('tr');
    console.log(row.attr('id'), row.data('price')); 


    added.push(row.attr('id'));
    localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(added));
    var storeddata=localStorage.getItem("cartItems");
    console.log(storeddata);   
  })
```

A example of the resulting array:

```
["0", "0", "0", "1", "1"]
```

Comment: a lot depends on your expectations for how this should work. Particularly with regard to server interaction and/or cart purchases. Overall question is far too broad. Try narrowing it down to more specific details

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not trying to have it send the details to a server at the moment, just to update the cart page with the basket contents. Just using this as an exercise to get my head around local storage and jquery/javascript

Comment: Then do some searching on how to filter one array based on another array. Would also be a lot simpler if you stored whole products, not just their id

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the array when you need to list the products like

```
var products = //Your Product Array
for(var i in storeddata)
{
      var id = storeddata[i];
      var obj = products.filter(function ( obj ) {
         return obj.id === id;
      })[0];
      console.log(obj);//This will be you product
}
```